# Calculating the throughput (requests/sec) and plot it

Tags: excel, apache, jmeter, throughput, jmeter-plugins

I'm using JMeter client to test the throughtput of a certain workload (PHP+MySQL, 1 page) on a certain server. Basically I'm doing a "capacity test" with an increasing number of threads over the time.

I installed the "Statistical Aggregate Report" JMeter plugin and this was the result (ignore the "Response time" line):
[image]

At the same time I used the "Simple Data Writer" listener to write a log file ("JMeter.csv"). Then I tried to "manually" calculate the throughput for every second of the test.

Each line of "JMeter.csv" has this format:

```
timestamp       elaspedtime   responsecode   success   bytes
1385731020607   42            200            true      325
...             ...           ...            ...       ...
```

The timestamp is referred to the time when the request is made by the client, and not when the request is served by the server. So I simply did: **totaltime = timestamp + elapsedtime**.

In the next step I converted the *totaltime* to a date format, like: **13:17:01**.

I have more than 14K samples and with Excel I was able to do this quickly.

Then I counted how many samples there were for each second. Example:

```
totaltime    samples (requestsServed/second)
13:17:01     204    
13:17:02     297
...          ...
```

When I tried to plot the results I obtained the following graphic:
[image]

As you can notice it is far different from the first graphic.

Given that the first graphic is correct, what is the mistake of my formula/procedure to calculate the throughput?

Comment: @pnuts What are you referring to? Can you give me an example?

Comment: YOu are right. I tried counting how many samples I have in each 1000 milliseconds but it changes nothing... For example: first sample=1385731060500, last sample=1385731061394; difference=894 milliseconds; samples=277. So I tried with: (277/894)*1000=~309 requests/second. But the first graphic, in the same period, shows a throughput of ~90.
I even tried with larger intervals, but it's even worse :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this plugin is plotting something that I don't know... I tried many times and my considerations were actually correct. Be careful with this plugin (or check its source code).

Answer (score 0):

Throughput can be view in Jmeter Summary Report and you can calculate by saving your Test Results file in xml file in Summary Report.

```
Throughput = Number of samples/(Max (ts+t) - Min ts)*1000
Throughput = (Number of samples/The difference between Maximum and minimum response time)*1000
```

By this formula you can calculate Throughput for each and every http requests in Summary Report.

Example:

```
Max Response Time = 1485538701633+569 = 1485538702202
Min Response Time = 1485538143112

Throughput = (2/1485538702202-1485538143112)*1000
Throughput = (2/1505) *1000
Throughput = 0.00132890*1000
Throughput = 1.3/sec
```

You can read more with examples Here(http://www.wikishown.com/how-to-calculate-throughput-in-jmeter/), i got a good idea about Throughput Calculation.